# Plugin to switch Firefox proxies easily?

Tags: proxy, firefox

When using proxies for pentesting, I usually have to switch my proxy in Firefox every 5 minutes. Unfortunately the proxy settings are 5 clicks deep buried in the settings.

I know that there are the [QuickProxy](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/quickproxy/) and [Elite Proxy Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/elite-proxy-switcher/), but they are both old and don't work with the current Firefox UI anymore.

Any recommendations?

Comment: I use FoxyProxy, but it's not on the official add-ons list, you have to Google it.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I've needed that occasionally, I've used **[FoxyProxy](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/foxyproxy-standard/)** – which would fit your needs quite well. With this addon (available at Mozilla's addon site, as the link shows), you can

- automatically switch proxies based on URLs
- manually switch between your default and *FoxyProxy* with just a single click (de/activating FoxyProxy and use either FoxyProxy or the system default)
- switch between different proxies with just two clicks (open the dropdown, select the proxy) or a single middle-click (cycles through your proxy list, see second screenshot)

[image: FoxyProxy] [image: FoxyProxy]
<sup>*FoxyProxy:* Proxy setup, selection drop-down (source: [FoxyProxy](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/foxyproxy-standard/); click images for larger variants)</sup>

I've been very happy with this extension, and can warmly recommend it.

Answer (score 2):

FoxyProxy is good, it has many options. [Proxy Selector](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/proxy-selector/) is just the basic version. It allows you to define proxies and switch easily. I'm using it from time to time on Firefox 42 and it works just fine.

Comment: ...For unknown reasons that simple and great addon has been removed from the Firefox addons library.
Latest version, signed by Mozilla, [on github here](https://github.com/maaaaz/proxy-selector-firefox-addon).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the reason you're switching proxies so often, you may be able to [write a Proxy Auto-Configuration file](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Proxy_servers_and_tunneling/Proxy_Auto-Configuration_PAC_file) that will implement the switching you want automatically.

You can then use the file by adding it under "Automatic proxy configuration URL" in the proxy settings, with the following format:

```
data:text/javascript;charset=utf-8;,function FindProxyForURL(url, host) { ... }
```