# Proxy to spoof geo-ip locations

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, ubuntu, proxy

### Required:

- Free
- Runs on Ubuntu 16.04 or Windows 7 or 10
- Choose spoof country

### Optional (But Nice):

- Runs on Ubuntu
- GUI
- Install through `apt-get`

Comment: System global? Or just for the browser? In the latter case, which browser(s) should be supported?

Comment: @Izzy browser is all that matters. And any major browser is fine. It's also fine if it comes with its own browser.

Comment: So if I would recommend you an addon for Firefox, that would be acceptable?

Comment: To not duplicate my answer, please see [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/26896/185) :)

Comment: @Izzy How would I use it to accomplish my goals? I don't know of any specific proxy servers I can use or how to find any.

Comment: There are several lists with proxies, e.g. at [HideMyAss](http://proxylist.hidemyass.com/) or [proxy-listen](http://www.proxy-listen.de/Proxy/Proxyliste.html). Take your pick, they even allow you to filter by country :)